# Add to Cart is not working in Angular

Tags: angular

I had set product id, option and quantity are to be required in backend. If I hardcoded values like this:

```
{ ProductId : 1, option: 'string', Quantity: 1 }
```

it works. But when I try to click ADD TO CART button with the below code it doesn't work.

Anyone help to fix this issue.

Product-details.html:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ProductId" #ProductId="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="cart.ProductId">
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h3 class="price-details-header" name="Option" #Option="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="cart.Option"></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" >
        <button type="button" data-toogle="tooltip" title="Decrement" (click)="decreaseQuantity(selectedproduct)" class="btn-decrement">- </button>&nbsp;
        <input  value="1" name="Quantity" #Quantity="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="cart.Quantity">&nbsp;
        <button type="button" data-toogle="tooltip" title="Increment" (click)="increaseQuantity(selectedproduct)" class="btn-increment"> + </button>&nbsp;&nbsp;  
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" (click)="addProductToCart()" routerLink="/cart">
        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-lg"></i> Add to Cart</a>
    </div>
```

Product-details.component.ts file:

```
export class ProductDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
    cart : Cart[];
    selectedproduct : any; 

    async addProductToCart() 
    {
        const response = await this.cartService.postCart(this.cart);

        if (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    }
```

Cart.service file:

```
async postCart(cart: Cart[]) {
    const response = await this.httpClient.post('myURL', cart,
        { observe: 'response', withCredentials: true }).toPromise();

    return response;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with doesn't work?

Comment: The product i want to add to cart is not added to cart

Comment: I think it should be `cart : Cart;` not `cart : Cart[];`.

Comment: No,its not working

Answer (score 0):

Your promise doesn't  return a correct object (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41810325/3387996), and you need to add it

```
   async addProductToCart() 
   {
    const response = await this.cartService.postCart(this.cart);
    if (response) {
      this.cart.push(response.json());
    }
   }
```